# possible to call testng annotation in method call?

Tags: java, testng

exercise for geeks!

I am using selenium webdriver with testng. Method `getDriver()` calls method `createDriver()` which returns `driver`.

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
           if (driver == null)
                driver = createDriver();
            return driver;
    }
```

I am using @Parameter("browser) from testng.xml on createDriver().

```
@Parameters("browser")
public WebDriver createDriver(String browser){
    //set browser capabilities
    return driver;
}
```

How can I make call `createDriver()` in `getDriver(`), provided I don't want to pass any arguments while calling it.

Comment: AFAIK `@Parameters` annotation works only when its coupled with an `@Test` annotation. In your sample `createDriver()` doesn't seem to be a test method. Can you please clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

Define browser parameter as global static in your code.

```
public static String BROWSER;
```

In your `beforeSuite`/`beforeMethod` read your `browser` parameter from `textng.xml` and pass its value to that `BROWSER` param.

```
public WebDriver createDriver(){
    //set browser capabilities
    // youre gonna use BROWSER now
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: what is the point of using @Parameters on method then? sorry, if I did not understand you correct.